# Can R read a zipped XLS file from a URL?

Tags: r, xls

Is it possible to read an Excel file from an online ZIP file?

I have been trying something like I would do with `read.csv`:

```
nuts = url("http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/ramon/documents/nuts/NUTS_2010.zip")
xlsx::read.xlsx(unz(nuts, "NUTS_2010.xls"), 1)
close(nuts)
```

… to no avail.

Comment: You should report the error/output you're getting.

Comment: Yes, sorry: `read.xlsx` returns "unknown path" (it does not understand the `unz()` connection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little less convenient, but how about:

```
basefn <- "NUTS_2010"
urlPath <- "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/ramon/documents/nuts/"
xlsFile <- paste0(basefn,".xls")
zipFile <- paste0(basefn,".zip")
download.file(paste0(urlPath,zipFile),zipFile)
unzip(zipFile)
## I had trouble with xlsx::read.xlsx, but gdata::read.xls was OK
## xlsx::read.xlsx(xlsFile,1)
gdata::read.xls(xlsFile)
unlink(zipFile)
```

You can always pack this into a `readZipURL <- function(urlPath,basefn) {...}` function if you want to do it on a regular basis (you might want to clean up the downloaded XLS file too ...)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to do it without downloading the ZIP file. ANy way your code might work without copying the ZIP to disk?

Comment: I think  you'd really have to look quite carefully at what both the unzipper *and* the XLS translator are doing -- they would both have to be capable of working in a streaming mode/working from pipes.  I guess you don't want to copy to disk because you're going to have a big ZIP file ... ?  You *might* be able to put something together with `gdata::xls2sep` (which normally creates a temporary file) sending to a pipe instead, which `read.csv` could read from ... too tricky for me to put together in my spare time, though.

Comment: I'll accept your solution -- I have no idea whether `read.xlsx` can actually work this way, and it's becoming too complicated to avoid downloading the ZIP in this case (it is not even that big).

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you want to avoid (temporarily) copying the file to disk?  Permissions problems, eventually wanting to work with big files, or just an aesthetic preference?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx4g" )
library(XLConnect)
temp <- tempfile()
zipfile <- paste0("https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Downloads/"
                  ,year,"/",year,"-", "Low-Income-Subsidy-Contract-Enrollment-by-County.zip")
download.file(zipfile,temp)

filename <- paste0("WEB Tables LIS by state -county ",month2,"-","1","-",year,".xlsx")

temp1 <- unzip(temp)
assign(paste0("scc_pdp_lis_",year),readWorksheetFromFile(temp1,sheet=1,startRow=7,header=F))
```

I am reading some CMS files I was interested on